# Redirection in multistep form CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, multi-step

I am creating a `multistep form` in CakePHP using http://bakery.cakephp.org/2012/09/09/Multistep-forms.html?
But it's not redirecting well. As I click `next` in step 1, it redirects me to `msf_index`.
Probably I'm not proceeding the right step count in the `msf_setup` method.
Why is this happening ?
Here is the Controller Code that I have just copy-pasted.

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

/**
 * use beforeRender to send session parameters to the layout view
 */
public function beforeRender() {
        parent::beforeRender();
        $params = $this->Session->read('form.params');
        $this->set('params', $params);
}

/**
 * delete session values when going back to index
 * you may want to keep the session alive instead
 */
public function msf_index() {
        $this->Session->delete('form');
}

/**
 * this method is executed before starting the form and retrieves one important parameter:
 * the form steps number
 * you can hardcode it, but in this example we are getting it by counting the number of files that start with msf_step_
 */
public function msf_setup() {
        App::uses('Folder', 'Utility');
        $usersViewFolder = new Folder(APP.'View'.DS.'Users');
        $steps = count($usersViewFolder->find('msf_step_.*\.ctp'));
        $this->Session->write('form.params.steps', $steps);
        $this->Session->write('form.params.maxProgress', 0);
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'msf_step', 1));
}

/**
 * this is the core step handling method
 * it gets passed the desired step number, performs some checks to prevent smart users skipping steps
 * checks fields validation, and when succeding, it saves the array in a session, merging with previous results
 * if we are at last step, data is saved
 * when no form data is submitted (not a POST request) it sets this->request->data to the values stored in session
 */
public function msf_step($stepNumber) {

        /**
         * check if a view file for this step exists, otherwise redirect to index
         */
        if (!file_exists(APP.'View'.DS.'Users'.DS.'msf_step_'.$stepNumber.'.ctp')) {
                $this->redirect('/users/msf_index');
        }

        /**
         * determines the max allowed step (the last completed + 1)
         * if choosen step is not allowed (URL manually changed) the user gets redirected
         * otherwise we store the current step value in the session
         */
        $maxAllowed = $this->Session->read('form.params.maxProgress') + 1;
        if ($stepNumber > $maxAllowed) {
                $this->redirect('/users/msf_step/'.$maxAllowed);
        } else {
                $this->Session->write('form.params.currentStep', $stepNumber);
        }

        /**
         * check if some data has been submitted via POST
         * if not, sets the current data to the session data, to automatically populate previously saved fields
         */
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

                /**
                 * set passed data to the model, so we can validate against it without saving
                 */
                $this->User->set($this->request->data);

                /**
                 * if data validates we merge previous session data with submitted data, using CakePHP powerful Hash class (previously called Set)
                 */
                if ($this->User->validates()) {
                        $prevSessionData = $this->Session->read('form.data');
                        $currentSessionData = Hash::merge( (array) $prevSessionData, $this->request->data);

                        /**
                         * if this is not the last step we replace session data with the new merged array
                         * update the max progress value and redirect to the next step
                         */
                        if ($stepNumber < $this->Session->read('form.params.steps')) {
                                $this->Session->write('form.data', $currentSessionData);
                                $this->Session->write('form.params.maxProgress', $stepNumber);
                                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'msf_step', $stepNumber+1));
                        } else {
                                /**
                                 * otherwise, this is the final step, so we have to save the data to the database
                                 */
                                $this->User->save($currentSessionData);
                                $this->Session->setFlash('Account created!');
                                $this->redirect('/users/msf_index');
                        }
                }
        } else {
                $this->request->data = $this->Session->read('form.data');
        }

        /**
         * here we load the proper view file, depending on the stepNumber variable passed via GET
         */
        $this->render('msf_step_'.$stepNumber);
}
```

}

The problem might be here:

```
 public function msf_setup() {
        App::uses('Folder', 'Utility');
        $usersViewFolder = new Folder(APP.'View'.DS.'Users');
        $steps = count($usersViewFolder->find('msf_step_.*\.ctp'));
        $this->Session->write('form.params.steps', $steps);
        $this->Session->write('form.params.maxProgress', 0);
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'msf_step', 1));
}
```

Also, I have added four `msf_setp` files in `view/Users` like
`msf_step_1, msf_step_2, msf_setp_3, msf_step_4`.

Please help. I'm Stuck. Thankx in advance.

Comment: Got it done.
Foolish mistake :)

Comment: How did you fix it ? I am stuck too :/